on DSM7 script with ssh runs well manually, fails when launched as same user in crontab
on DSM7 script with ssh runs well manually, fails when launched as same user in crontab:
Host key verification failed.
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(254) [sender=3.1.2]


The error sounds like the script from cron uses a different ~/.ssh/known_hosts or can't access the existing one. That is often caused by the limited and/or different environment that cron sets up (compared to a normal interactive shell)

Does this answer your question? Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?

@HBruijn, thank you but this is what's suspected..as for my question it reads 'how can I troubleshoot it?'
